# How can I bring my server online?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, host

I don't think if it's possible, but I would like to bring my server temporarily online.
The thing is, I have been working on a PHP project lately from my home computer, and I need to show the progress to my follow team mates on their PC. Unfortunately I cannot go to them, but I wish if my website could.

We don't have a registered domain for it yet.
It's an APACHE v2.0 server installed, running PHP 5 and MySQL at the same time.
Is there some way I could possibly do that.

I heard some where that it's possible with Forwarding ports on DNS using static IP address or something like that. I am using Internet Connection using a HUWAEI Data Card Modem Model: E1550. Unfortunately, I cannot forward ports wit hit.

Any possibility I could share the website temporarily?

Comment: do yourself a favour and buy some shared hosting, it's extremely cheap. you can get very cheap domain names too with `.info`

Comment: I really cannot go to spend money on something that's not Finished yet! Could you guide me on free hosts that provide all these functionality? Or the DNS thing if not?

Comment: if you can access your website through your IP, most likely everyone can.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just open up a free hosting account on a real good free host service like 000webhost, export your local database, upload your site to the remote host using ftp, then import your databases export file into the remote host's mysql and share the link to your site with your buddies?
That's what I do.

Comment: Yeah, I really like them, too.  The cool thing about that company is that the free service they give is better than some of the paid hosting plans I've used.  Hey, if you like my answer, please click on the upvote button.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I wish I could, only if I had 15 reputations. I'm down to 6. And now stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post questions as well!! Sorry can't help it.

Answer (score 0):

- Install and set up Apache properly
- Forward port 80 (or other, if you want) to your local IP, through your gateway settings
- Register with your IP on DynDns.org or no-ip.org or something like that.

Edit: Well, you said "temporarily", you can just forward port 80 to your local IP and be happy with your "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/" but beware that it will change whenever you restart the router, or reestablish the connection.

Comment: Also, please check out http://xip.io it's a wildcard DNS that doesn't need an account or any configuration, just use http://something.[myexternalIP].xip.io as domain-name, for example: http://foo.192.168.1.1.xip.io will automatically resolve to ip-address 192.168.1.1 very handy, also to test your website on an iPad, which doesn't have a 'hosts' file :) You will still have to set up port forwarding on your router though, can't get around that

Answer (score 0):

What @MarkoD said, but until then -

If you have access to your router's firmware, you forward ports from there, not your actual PC. Just forward the port Apache is listening on, then put WAMP/XAMPP online.

Once it's online, share your IP and the port you chose with your team mates and they should be able to connect.

The link should look something like: `http://111.111.111.111:2222`.

For example, Cox Communications doesn't allow outgoing data on port 80 or 443, so use 8080

`http://111.111.111.111:8080`

If your ISP does, then just use 80 and drop the `:xxxx`.